# Gitlab CI get "[Launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform" for Angular app

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, gitlab-ci, chromium, angular-unit-test

I can serve my Angular project locally and as well get passed **Karma** and **Jasmin** report on `http://localhost:9876` but during running test process in terminal, get this error:

```
Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
```

and my Gitlab CI as run pipeline returns `[launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.` that gets fail.

As I saw in many posts about it, most of them refer to set `export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser` and although I did it for both `.bashrc` and `.profile`, still get this error
Also I get this error in gitlab-ci after use `trion/ng-cli-karma:10.0.6`

I tried to install it as `before_script` but still doesnt fix.

> both of local machine and docker container have linux OS (Debian and Ubuntu)